# Writing two different hex values to linked shift registers

Tags: led

I'm new to raspberry pi and electronics, and I'm working on improving my first (meaning my design, no tutorials) project. My original project was two seven-segment displays linked to two shift registers; I controlled each by controlling each shift register separately. I'm rebuilding it so that the two registers are linked, so I only control the first.

The problem is getting two different numbers to display. I have all the hex values from the previous project, and the best I can get it to do is display  the same number on both displays. I want to be able to display different numbers on each display. I suspect its something with the bit shifting I'm not doing right...

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# The pins
dataPin = 40
refPin = 38
clckPin = 36

# Set everything up
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(dataPin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(refPin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(clckPin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)

# The numbers
# These have their binary equivalent, for example:
# 0x3F = 0011 1111-> Prints the number zero by turning off the
# decimal display and the middle inside segment, and turning
# everything else on.
numbers = [0x3F, 0x06, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0x07, 0x7F, 0x6F]

def call_clck():
    GPIO.output(clckPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    GPIO.output(clckPin, GPIO.LOW)

# Writes the data to the shift register
# This came from my last project and some examples I could find
def write_no(data):
    for bit in range(0,16):
        GPIO.output(dataPin, 0x8000 & (data << bit)) 
        call_clck()

    GPIO.output(refPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    GPIO.output(refPin, GPIO.LOW)

# Write two numbers
write_no(0x5B66)
time.sleep(2)

# End program
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Btw, that's not the original code; I've tried a lot between yesterday and today, I feel like I'm missing something really simple... Google hasn't really turned up a lot. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit**
I commented the code; hope its clearer.
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B. My wiring uses 74HC595 shift registers.

Also, here's a picture of my progress: Sorry, that's as clear and neat as I can make it.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please preferably use the imgur image hosting service for inline images. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to decipher your code (TL;DR), or divine what your wiring looks like (you didn't provide this), or what device you're using (you didn't provide this), I can only think of this to offer:

I *think* what you're trying to do requires that you **multiplex** the two displays. I mention this because you didn't mention the word **multiplex** in your question, nor do I see any reference to anything that looks like  that in your code. Since I'm out on a limb with these assumptions, I'll not waste any more bandwidth in expanding on my ***answerguess***. However, if you think that **multiplexing** might be the clue you needed, here's a [link that explains **multiplexing** in some detail.](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/0-99-counter-using-avr-atmega32)

Answer (score 0):

Though hard to decipher from the picture provided (a schematic would have been more useful) you are providing the same data to both shift registers, so obviously both 7-segment displays will show the same number.

You need to connect the serial data output (pin 9) of your first shift register to the serial data input (pin 14) of the 2nd shift register. You appear to have both pin 14s wired together.